# Multiple fopens - only first one works

Tags: php, apache, fopen

I've a strange issue I am encountering. Recently I switched from webhosting to a VPS, mainly because of flexibility a VPS provides me with.

I now however need to setup Apache on my own and I'm not to good at doing so.

I've a `.php` file and I have 2 `fopen` in it. The first one does it's job but the second one doesn't work for some reason.

I was wondering, is there some `php.ini` settings I need to make to allow multiple `fopen` in a file ?

### EDIT

Code below:

```
        $fp = fopen('ticket' . $_SESSION['id'] . '.txt', 'a+');
        $savestring = "---";
        fwrite($fp, $savestring);              
        fclose($fp);
        $_SESSION['total'] = $total;
        $fp = fopen('reqs.txt', 'a+');
        $savestring = PHP_EOL . "Ticket Nou: " . $_SESSION['id'] . " | Ora: " . $ordertime . " | IP: " . $ip;
        fwrite($fp, $savestring);              
        fclose($fp);
```

I shortened the $savestrings, in reality they are longer. The issue occurs with the second file, reqs.txt.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No error, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [flock](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

I have a file with 4 fopen it didn't work.

after using flock it worked.

Comment: Can you be more explicit, this `flock` thing makes me really confuse.